# How can I link multiple routes to the same ui view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My current example is using the first template every time, it doesn't update the template with the nested state.

Just imagine both angular components have a template of a `h1` and that's it, very simple.

Two states:

```
var people = { 
  name: 'people', 
  url: '/people', 
  component: 'people'
}

var person= { 
  name: 'people.person', 
  url: '/person', 
  component: 'person'
}
```

State register:

```
states.forEach(state => $stateProvider.state(state));
```

Inside People template:

```
<h1>People</h1>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.state.go('people.person')">Go to person</button>
```

Inside `people.person`, I've exposed an ng-click which will redirect back to people.

```
<h1>People.Person</h1>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.state.go('people')">Go to People</button>
```

The controllers are very simple, just imagine:

```
controller : function($state) {
   this.state = $state;
}
```

Why doesn't the people.person template work, it inherits from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a child route that specifies the same component as its parent. If you remove the component line from person, it should work. I recently got burned by this. It worked in ui-router prior to 1.0.3.

Comment: But they aren't the same component, there's people & person?

Comment: Good point. :) Where is the code that defines what person you're navigating too and what does the template that contains the ui-view look like? I'm wondering if there's some issue with person being a child of people and the ui-view directives not being nested or something. Also, what version of ui-router are you using?

Comment: I'm using angular@1.6.2, What isn't overly clear inside the docs is that you need to nest the ui-view directive inside the child state. I've added an answer to this post mate!